# Thinking-sphinx and relevance or similarity score

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Does someone know if there is a way to get the raw relevance or similarity score between a query and a result when using sphinx in general or thinking-sphinx as a wrapper? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

@results.each_with_weighting do |result, weight| 
  # ... 
end

from the comments on http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx

Comment: Awesome, was trying to find this for a while. You just made my day :-)